# Filling values in a tibble column up and down while doing math

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset of live capture data, and a small tooth was extracted for aging before releasing the animal (it's a small premolar they can live without). However, for some animals we were only able to age them on the recapture.

For example:

```
# Aged at first capture
 ID     exit ageindays   age
1 3      67       341 0.934
2 3      79        NA    NA 
3 3      86        NA    NA 
4 3     101        NA    NA 
5 3     119        NA    NA
```

vs

```
# Aged on recapture
   ID     exit ageindays  age
 1  4     428         NA   NA 
 2  4     435         NA   NA 
 3  4     441      1145   3.14 
 4  4     462         NA   NA 
 5  4     470         NA   NA 
 6  4     471         NA   NA
```

I'd like to fill in the "age" column (age in years) for each individual, based on the number of days before or after the date they were aged.

This is the code I've tried:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
          mutate(ageindays=case_when(!is.na(ageindays) ~ ageindays, 
                                     is.na(ageindays) ~ first(ageindays) + exit)) %>%
          ungroup() %>%
          mutate(age=as.numeric(ageindays/365))
```

But I think I am using `first()` incorrectly because it seems like it is doing the math based on the first row of the data frame. This is similar output to what I'd expect, but the output shows correct age calculation for lines 1-5 (some cut out), but then things get goofy from line 69 onwards (after the initial age estimate of 341 days/0.934 years for individual 3). It looks like this happens each time the data frame switches to a new ID.

```
       ID     exit ageindays   age
    <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
  1 1      65           704   1.93 
  2 1      79           783   2.15 
  3 1      86           790   2.16 
  4 1     101           805   2.21 
  5 1     106           810   2.22 
  . .      .             .      .
  . .      .             .      .
  . .      .             .      .
  . .      .             .      .
 61 2      65           1069  2.93 
 62 2     119            823  2.25 
 63 2     120            824  2.26 
 64 2     123            827  2.27 
 65 2     164            868  2.38 
 66 2     183            887  2.43 
 67 2     199            903  2.47 
 68 3      67            341  0.934
 69 3      79            783  2.15 
 70 3      86            790  2.16 
 71 3     101            805  2.21 
 72 3     119            823  2.25 
 73 3     150            854  2.34
```

Example data, new IDs because shorter capture histories. Was tinkering with a few things, so columns have been updated with the date of capture ("AgeDay"), and the age in days at capture:

```
structure(list(ID = c("5", "5", "5", "6", 
"6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6"
), exit = c(408, 409, 437, 679, 682, 688, 694, 702, 716, 723, 
729), AgeDay = c(408, 
408, 408, 679, 679, 679, 679, 679, 679, 679, 679), ageindays = c(317, 
317, 317, 588, 588, 588, 588, 588, 588, 588, 588)), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you include a small example of the output you expect to get?

Comment: I think the `?approx()` function will do this for you nice and cleanly. Could you share your sample input for IDs 3 and 4 using `dput()` so it is copy/pasteable for testing? `df %>% filter(ID %in% 3:4) %>% dput()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your given data, using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr) # >= 1.1.0, otherwise use "group_by"

df %>% 
  mutate(ageindays = ageindays + cumsum(c(0, diff(exit))), 
         age = ageindays / 365.25, .by = ID)
# A tibble: 11 × 5
   ID     exit AgeDay ageindays   age
   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 5       408    408       317 0.868
 2 5       409    408       318 0.871
 3 5       437    408       346 0.947
 4 6       679    679       588 1.61 
 5 6       682    679       591 1.62 
 6 6       688    679       597 1.63 
 7 6       694    679       603 1.65 
 8 6       702    679       611 1.67 
 9 6       716    679       625 1.71 
10 6       723    679       632 1.73 
11 6       729    679       638 1.75
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>%
  mutate(birthday = ageindays - exit) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  tidyr::fill(birthday, .direction = "downup") %>%
  mutate(ageindays2 = exit + birthday,
         age2 = ageindays2 / 365) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 6 × 7
     ID  exit ageindays   age birthday ageindays2  age2
  <int> <int>     <int> <dbl>    <int>      <int> <dbl>
1     4   428        NA NA         704       1132  3.10
2     4   435        NA NA         704       1139  3.12
3     4   441      1145  3.14      704       1145  3.14
4     4   462        NA NA         704       1166  3.19
5     4   470        NA NA         704       1174  3.22
6     4   471        NA NA         704       1175  3.22
```